# How to define pointcut for advice execution joinpoint?

Tags: aop, aspectj

As i know we can define pointcut even for an advice. example

```
package com.master_scrum.aop;
import org.aspectj.lang.JoinPoint;
import org.aspectj.lang.annotation.Aspect;
import org.aspectj.lang.annotation.Before;
import org.aspectj.lang.annotation.Pointcut;

@Aspect
public class ConstructorAspect {
   @Before("execution(com.master_scrum.Account.new(..)")
   public void beforeExecuteConstructor(JoinPoint jp){
    System.out.println("Do somthing good");
   }
}
```

now how i can create another advice for this advice? What is synctax?
i've tried with this one but does not work:

```
package com.master_scrum.aop;
import org.aspectj.lang.JoinPoint;
import org.aspectj.lang.annotation.Aspect;
import org.aspectj.lang.annotation.Before;
import org.aspectj.lang.annotation.Pointcut;

@Aspect
public class AspectOfConstructorAspect {
 @Before("execution("* ConstructorAspect.*(..))") //aspects are in same package
 public void beforeAspect(JoinPoint jp){
   System.out.println("Before constructor advice");
 }
}
```

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

i found solution from AspectJ manual
just define pointcut like this

```
package com.master_scrum.aop;
import org.aspectj.lang.JoinPoint;
import org.aspectj.lang.annotation.Aspect;
import org.aspectj.lang.annotation.Before;
import org.aspectj.lang.annotation.Pointcut;

@Aspect
public class AspectOfConstructorAspect {
 @Before("adviceexecution() && within(com.master_scrum.aop.ConstructorAspect)") 
 public void beforeAspect(JoinPoint jp){
   System.out.println("Before constructor advice");
 }
}
```

Comment: Happy to see you are using the manual links I provided you with last time. :) In this case you almost guessed the pointcut name `adviceexecution()` directly in your subject line: _How to define pointcut for **advice execution** joinpoint?_ ;-)

Comment: @kriegaex yes, you're have a good eyes, and also be a master of aspectj and aop.luck me when meet you in this topic. i saw your name in almost corner of aspectj